# Create a Ramdisk with predefined folder structure possible?

Tags: mount, fstab

I have a ramdisk defined in fstab and it's been working perfectly:

`ramdisk1  /media/ramdisk  ramfs defaults,size=8G,x-gvfs-show  0  0`

Recently I want to change the ramdisk in such a way that when the system boots, the ramdisk will be mounted with some predefined empty folders inside.

Is this possible? I feel like I can simply add more lines in fstab for the sub-folders, but then I have to define a quota for them which I don't want. Is there a simple way to define this while all the sub-folders will use the total 8GB quota of the ramdisk?

Update: The answer from David is probably the way to go, doing one way restore with empty folders only. Thanks!

Comment: Read this article it may help you. https://linuxhint.com/ramdisk_ubuntu_1804/

Comment: I don't know when the `cron` process starts, but if it is after when the ramdisk is available, then maybe you can create a cronjob with the time being `@reboot`?

Comment: I would just create whatever folder structure I need from a cron job as @Ray suggests - cron job definitely runs after filesystems are mounted, because I use cron job running `@reboot` on my system to remount some snaps r/w and modify them.